# What is the exact meaning of localhost on the operating system?

Tags: networking

I have seen `127.0.0.1` is local host address. But what is it and what is the differences between this and my local adapter like LAN  IP address or WLAN IP address. Is there any connection between this `l27.0.0.1` and my LAN or WLAN Network card?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 address the machine itself and only visible on the machine itself. Everything other address is visible to another devices on the network.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 refer to which device in computer ? I am sure it is not Network lan interface when you say devise itself which part you exactly mean?

Comment: @alex: `127.0.0.1` refers to a virtual network interface, usually called `loopback` (or `lo` for short). This interface does not have any physical components, it is fully implemented in the OS.

Comment: thanks my question is this where is this virtual network or loopback  or 127.0.0.1 sir? I mean in where they implement this vitual network?

Comment: @alex - **The machine itself.**  My comment is very specific.

Comment: @alex | It is on your computer and is implemented when the computer wants to talk to itself.

Comment: Aha... thanks dear all . I think I get u all say the 127.0.0.1 refer to virtual network and they implemented this on the os .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is an IP that's part of the IANA reserved range for loopback use (the full range is 127.0.0.1-127.255.255.255).

A loopback NIC (always a virtual NIC provided by the OS, never a physical NIC) simply takes any traffic it receives and then throws right back out of that same virtual NIC.  It's like the adapter is "connected to itself."

Your loopback NIC is it's own network adapter and not connected in any way to your LAN or WLAN NIC.

On some operating systems (such as Linux or Cisco IOS, not sure about Windows), you can create multiple loopback NICs.  127.0.0.1 is a (possibly defacto) standard for at least one of them, and it's generally expected at least one loopback NIC exists on any TCP/IP capable system with this IP.

This is used a lot to provide TCP/IP services only on the local system and not to any external machine.

`localhost` is typically in your `/etc/hosts`* file, and assigned to the IP 127.0.0.1.

Your system will usualy consult `/etc/hosts` to resolve DNS names before talking to an outside DNS server.  (This is changeable under Linux).

So, if you type `http://localhost`, your system's DNS resolver will hit the `/etc/hosts` file before making a query to a DNS server.  It picks up on the `localhost 127.0.0.1` entry in your `/etc/hosts`, and thus has the same effect as if you typed `http://127.0.0.1`.

So `localhost` is just a "domain name" for 127.0.0.1, in your `/etc/hosts` file.  And 127.0.0.1 should almost always be your loopback NIC.

---

*on Windows this is actually `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Answer (score 3):

`127.0.0.1` is the equivalent of saying "my house". It's meaningful, but only to you. When your friend says "my house" it means a completely different house. It implies no information needed to get there from where you are.

**LAN IP** (assuming you're in a typical setup with DHCP Proxy) is the equivalent of saying "Alex's bedroom". It is meaningful ONLY to other people already in your house (on your LAN), but if you are in the house, everybody can get to Alex's Bedroom and knows where to find it.  However, telling somebody across town (somewhere else on the internet) to meet you at "Alex's Bedroom" is not going to work; they will never find it. Google maps needs more info.

**WAN IP** in this example is like your street address. It is enough information for anybody in the world to get to your front door.  It is not going to enable them to find their way to "Alex's Bedroom" however, unless you provide special access to them (port forwarding/DMZ host).

Answer (score 2):

`127.0.0.1` is a reserved IP loopback address. It is used for things like testing the communication of your own host or give access to network services run on the host (such as a web server). In this example you have a web server running on your host machine. When you access this through a web browser using `localhost` your system is making a network request to itself (loopback).

It differs from your LAN address in that your LAN IP is assigned by the DHCP on your router and can be accessed and edited from both internally and externally on the network. This isn't the case with `localhost` as it is a universal constant on all systems. The `localhost` address is the same at `127.0.0.1`

Source - [What-is-What](http://www.what-is-what.com/what_is/127.0.0.1.html)
Source - [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback)